# Android AsyncTask errors with onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have a question regarding the AsyncTask class in android, and why it is giving me an error.  I have defined an inner class here..

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Integer>{


            Context context;
                ProgressDialog dialog;
                MyTask(Context c)
                {
                    this.context = c;
                }

                //@Override
                protected void onPreExecute()
                {
                     dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                dialog.setMessage("Scanning Ports!");
                    dialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for(intBeg =  intBeg; intBeg <= intEnd; intBeg++             
                    {
                        try
                        {
                        Socket s = new Socket(strMachine, intBeg);
                        isConnected += strMachine + " Is Listening On Port: " + intBeg + "\n";
                        Log.d("PORTSCAN", isConnected);
                        s.close();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            notConnected += strMachine + " Is Not Listening On Port: " + intBeg + "\n";                         
                            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), 3000).show();
                            Log.d("PORTSCAN", notConnected);

                        }
                    }


                    return 1;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Integer... params)
                {

                }
                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params)
                {

                }





            }
```

However, when the doInBackground finishes, it supposed to call onPostExecute(), which never happens. And even when i try to use the "@Override" annotation over the onPostExecute(), it gives me an error saying onPostExecute must override a superclass method. I dont get what is happening! any help? Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have imported correct class that is, android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPostExcecute(Integer result)` takes a single argument (no ...).

If the arguments don't match, it will not match the super method and will therefore not override it (and be called). Generally if `@Override` gives you an error something is wrong with your method name/parameters (or the superclass does not have such a method).

Comment: Thanks, It works great now! I was using (Integer... params), when it should have been just (Integer params)

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer params)//its single Integer object, not array of Integer objects
```

its java [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).`and you can't change parameter of overrided method`,You just change the Behaviour of override method.And its method of `AsyncTask Class.`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this onPostExecuteMethod

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.e("LOG", " on Post");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
private class DownloadingProgressTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowDescription.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
            downloadFile(b.getString("URL"));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDescription.this,
                    "File successfully downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            imgDownload.setVisibility(8);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDescription.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}
```